# Japan shore pass

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, indian-citizens, canada, japan

Can an Indian citizen going to Canada with Canada study visa who has layover at Haneda airport,Japan can have shore pass and visit the city during the layover time without any hassle .

Comment: How long is your layover? https://www.in.emb-japan.go.jp/transit%20visas.html

Comment: 16 hours (ANA FLIGHT )

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you have a travel ticket within 72 hours and there are no other connecting flights on the same day. Most sites I found say that the Shore Pass application is usually handled by your airline, so I would recommend contacting them before booking / ASAP before you travel.

You are eligible for the Japan Shore Pass if:

- You have all the required documents for the final country of destination
- You have enough financial means to cover the duration of your stay
- You will arrive and depart from an airport or seaport located in the same groups (for your itinerary this is Group A airports: Narita (NRT), Haneda (HND), Nagoya (NGO), Niigata (KIJ), Komatsu (KMQ) and Yokota (OKO)).

Source: [VisaGuideWorld](https://visaguide.world/asia/japan-visa/transit/)

You can also check by inputting your full details and itinerary into [IATA](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/) and/or [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b&clear=true), the system used by airlines