# 6 hour Layover in San Francisco

Tags: usa, transit, layovers

I have a 6 hour layover in San Francisco on my way to Canada. Do I need USA VISA ?If yes which type of visa do I need and How do I apply that ?

Comment: No one can answer this since you haven't supplied your citizenship. Please add that information into your question. (Press **Edit**)

Comment: If you need a visa for entering the US you (almost always) also need one for a layover of any length of time.

Comment: As a note, learn to use the tool in the link in my answer. It'll save you from having to ask similar questions :]

Comment: BART comes right into the international terminal and goes downtown or the Mission. Lovely city, best food this side of Paris. But bring a jacket, it's chilly in many parts of the City!

Answer (score 3):

Given that you asked a question about [Japan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/182117/japan-shore-pass) where you say that you are an Indian citizen, I will assume the same for this answer.

- Assuming the following:
- Origin: India
- Destination: Canada
- Transit: SFO
- Citizenship: Indian

In short, yes you need a US visa for a transit through a US airport. You can apply for a C visa (transit) or a regular visitor visa (B1/B2). Either way, you WILL have to pass through US CBP immigration inspection even on a simple transit on your way to another country. You need to contact the closest [US representation](https://in.usembassy.gov/) in your country/area and apply for the appropriate visa through them. No one here can tell you how to do that better than the authority itself. See below for requirements ([provided by United Airlines' tool](https://www.united.com/en/us/timatic/))

Note: You will also need to meet entry requirements for Canada (visa).

[image: USA transit Indian citizen]

Comment: +1, but I would advise the OP to find flights that don't connect via the US, it would save them a lot of hassle.  All major East Asian airlines fly direct to Canada.

Comment: @lambshaanxy Absolutely agree it's better to avoid the hassle, but that wasn't part of their question so I omitted it.

Comment: Note that some consulates have waiting time of 2 years or more to get an appointment for a visa, even for a transit visa. So yes, an alternative routing is probably a good idea.